# Как убрать рамку в выпадающем списке select?

Tags: html, css

Как убрать рамку в выпадающем списке `select`? Не рамку самого `select`, не рамку элемента `option`, а именно границу выпадающего списка. `border: none;` и `outline: none;` не работают.

Comment: Это не стилизуется. Для "другого" `select` - лучше делать свой `select`.

Comment: @ksa т.е. грубо говоря из div-ов?

Comment: Если грубо то - да, из `div`. Но семантически тут больше уместны списки. ;)

Comment: @ksa Спасибо)) 2023 на дворе а у нас `select` не стилизуется)))

Comment: Так уже у каждого свой есть. Т.ч. никому не надо. :-D У нас так целый справочник для выбора значений реализован, а ты все про `select` переживаешь. :)